Cramer's Rule when the determinant of coefficient matrix is zero?
I checked Cramer's rule in several textbooks. All of them only consider the case where the determinant of the coefficient matrix is non-zero. But what if it is zero? I think the answer should be:

A1) If all the numerators in Cramer's rule are zeros, then there are infinitely many solutions.
A2) If there is any no-zero numerators in Cramer's rule, then there is no solution.

It is trivially true when $n=1$. I was wondering whether there is a textbook explicitly stating this result, or some results that can imply this result.
Edit: I should change the condition "the column to the right of equal signs is a zero vector" to "all the numerators in Cramer's rule are zeros."

How exactly do you expect this extended Cramer's rule to work? If the coefficient matrix has determinant zero, then the bottom of the fraction that gives the components of the solution will be zero. Interestingly, if any of the numerators is non-zero, then we can guarantee that a solution does not exist. However, it is possible for the system to have no solution even when all of the numerators are zero

When the coefficient matrix is not invertible, there will be either no solutions or infinitely many solutions, depending on the constant vector on the right-hand side. So no criterion involving only the coefficient matrix will resolve this question.

@Ypbor As I said in my earlier comment, A1 is false but A2 is true.

(A1) is not true. For example, the system $$\begin{cases} x_1 + x_2 \phantom{{} + x_3 + x_4} = 1 \\ \phantom{x_1 + x_2 + {}} x_3 + x_4 = 1 \\ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 2 \\ x_1 + x_2 - x_3 - x_4 = 1\end{cases}$$
All numerators in Cramer's formulas are zero, but there are no solutions.
To know when there are no solutions and when there are infinitely many, we use statements like Kronecker-Capelli theorem.

Ah, sorry, I realized I misrepresented my idea. Please refer to my edit of the question.

I changed the counterexample so it also works for the new statement

Wait, my new statement is "If all the numerators in Cramer's rule are zeros, then there are infinitely many solutions." So you provide an example rather than a counterexample.

Right, sorry. Changed again.

If $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then one can formulate Cramer's rule as follows:
Let $A_{ij}$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by removing the $i$-th row and $j$-th column and let $c_{ij} = \det(A_{ij})$. Then if $\text{adj}(A)$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with entries $\text{adj}(A)_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j}c_{ji}$ we have
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
A.\text{adj}(A)= \text{adj}(A).A = \det(A).I_n
$$
This identity is true whether or not the determinant is nonzero.
Thinking of $\det$ as a function of the columns of $A$, its defining properties show that $\det(A)=0$ if the column rank is less than $n$, so the image of the map $x \mapsto Ax$ is not all of $\mathbb R^n$ and thus $A$ cannot be invertible.
On the other hand, if $\det(A)$ is nonzero, you can divide the identity $(\dagger)$ by $\det(A)$ to see that $\frac{1}{\det(A)}\text{adj}(A)$ must be the inverse of $A$, showing that the condition that $\det(A)\neq 0$ is necessary and sufficient for $A$ to be invertible.
Now whenever a matrix is invertible, for any $b \in \mathbb R^n$, the equation $Ax=b$ has a unique solution, namely $x=A^{-1}b$.
What can be said when $\det(A)=0$?
Since the entries of $\text{adj}(A)$ are determinants of $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ submatrices of $A$, when $\det(A)=0$ the column rank of $A$ can be at most $(n-1)$ and hence the columns of $\text{adj}(A)$ are all multiples of each other, so that $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ has rank $1$ when $A$ has rank $n-1$, and is identically zero if $A$ has rank less than $n-1$.
We thus get no information in the case where $A$ has rank less than $n-1$, however in the case where $A$ has rank $n-1$, the adjugate matrix still gives useful information: since $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ has rank $1$ all of its rows are multiples of each other as are all of its columns. The identity $(\dagger)$ when $\mathrm{rank}(A)=n-1$ becomes $A.\mathrm{adj}(A)= \mathrm{adj}(A).A = 0$, so that any nonzero column of $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ spans the kernel of $A$, and any row of $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ gives a linear equation cutting out the image -- i.e. the columns space of $A$.
Equivalently, if $b \in \mathbb R^n$, the equation $Ax=b$ has a solution if and only if $\mathrm{adj}(A)(b)=0$, and in that case there are infinitely many solutions, with any two differing by a multiple of a nonzero column of $\mathrm{adj}(A)$.

Thank you for your answer. But I think Cramer's rule also indicates when $det(A)\neq 0$, there is a unique solution. Your identity seems to be silent about the number of solutions.

When a linear system/matrix is invertible there is always a unique solution: $Ax=b$ if and only if $x=A^{-1}b$.

I mean your statement is silent about the number of solutions when $det(A)\neq0$.

Cramer’s rule can be applied when the coefficient $\text{det}\not=0$. When observing a $2\times 2$ matrix with a coefficient $\text{det}=0$, the system is incompatible when the numerator determinants are nonzero and indeterminate when the numerator determinants are zero.
However, we cannot say the same for $3\times 3$ or higher. In this case, having all determinants equal to $0$ does not mean the system is indeterminate. The only conclusion we can draw here is that the system is inconsistent when coefficient $\text{det}=0$ and any of the numerator $\text{det}\not=0$.

I think by "incompatible" you mean "no solution". But what do you mean by "the system is indeterminate"?

By incompatible I mean the system is incompatible with Cramer's rule, and it cannot be used for the system. An indeterminate system is a system with more than one solution, usually infinitely many as the solution can be expressed in terms of one or more parameters.

Consider linear system $Ax=b$, where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is singular.
A1) is wrong; A2) is correct.

For A1). Consider the counterexample $A=\mathbf{0},b=\mathbf{1}$: all numerators are zero, but no solution.
For A2). There exists a nonzero numerator, this implies
$rank([A,b]) = n > rank(A)$. Hence, no solution due to Kronecker-Capelli Theorem.

For A1) "all the numerators in Cramer's rule are zeros": This condition does not guarantee $b\in range(A)$. For example, when $rank(A)<n-1$, for any $b\notin range(A)$, all those numerators in Cramer's rule are zeros, but there is no solution.
For A2) $|A| = 0 \implies dim(range(A)) < n$. If $b \in range(A)$, then $b$ and any $n-1$ column vectors of $A$ cannot span $\mathbb{R}^n$, which means all the numerators in Cramer's rule must be zero.
Rule of thumb:

If $b\in range(A)$, then $x_s + null(A)$ are also the solutions, where $Ax_s=b$.
If $b\notin range(A)$, no solution.


I am sorry but how is your answer related to the determinant of $A$?

Just show the general situation about no solution, single solution or infinitely many solutions. When $|A| = 0$, it's not invertible, but $b$ doesn't have to be zero vector to have infinitely many solutions. As long as b in the range space of A, we have infinitely many solutions when A is singular.

My bad, I misrepresented my idea. Please refer to my edit of my question.

So you basically imply my statement is correct. But I was wondering what the proof is. I would also appreciate it if you could refer to a statement in a textbook if you find the proof too tedious to type.

@Ypbor I deleted my last comment. Your statement is wrong. We can easily find counterexamples. The easiest one: $A = \mathbf{0}, b = \mathbf{1}$

Why is this a counterexample? My statement is "If there is any no-zero numerator, there is no solution." Your example is consistent with it.

@Ypbor I'm confused. "If all the numerators in Cramer's rule are zeros, then there are infinitely many solutions." Isn't this your statement?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thank you for editing the question and the new A1+A2 format looks clearer. I think I understand your argument about A2. As for A1, I get your argument about $rank(A)<n-1$. However, if $rank(A)=n-1$, I think A1 is correct. and I believe that is what the answer from @krm2233 implies, even though I haven't fully digested his answer. Actually, your counterexample would not be a counterexample if $n=1$ and that's exactly a case where $rank(A)=n-1$.

As I said in my answer, please go to digest Kronecker-Capelli Theorem and its proof. That’s all you need.
